# missing columns when I save my dataframe as a .txt

Tags: r, write.table

So, I am saving my dataframe as a .txt by using this code:

```r
write.table(FinalLongFormat, file = "../data/FinalLongFormattxt", 
            sep = "\t", dec = ".", row.names = F, col.names = T)
```

My dataframe is looking perfectly fine inside Rstudio, but all the values from my last three columns are missing when I save it as a .txt file. I attached a picture to show what it looks like:

[image: picture of txt.file]

Hopefully someone here is familiar with his problem:)

Comment: Your output is tab-delimited, but it sounds like you want fixed-width format. If that's the case, perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/54751514/3358272 will help. (In addition, the `gdata` package has `write.fwf`, I believe, which might be suitable for you as well.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All 11 columns are there (in your image), they just aren't aligned with the column headers.