# how to create standard text file format for National death index in sas or R

Tags: r, sas

I want to create a **standard text file format** with 100 positions per patient as in the attached screenshot ( ignoring the first 2 rows) to get the death date as requested by the National Death Index.  I tried that in `sas` and then exported it as `.txt` but I noticed that columns width were not properly aligned upon opening that in the Notepad. They don't want to keep headings but we need to keep stated width.

[image]
[image]

Here is my sample fictitious dataset (that I have in Excel) and my used code

```
Abei    Ghador          07  16  1992                                            
Aziz    Patrick         07  01  1947                                            
Ali Theodore            07  01  1966                                            
Abdelrahman Baker   A       05  01  1966                                            
Abd Farik           11  01  1971                                            
Abele   Mat A       04  01  1994
```

Here are some of my efforts in `sas` as I kept merging each column to the combined data but the final .txt did not meet their requirements.

```
data combinedAoDB;  merge LastName1 FirstName2 ;run;
data combinedAoDB;  merge combinedAoDB MIDDLEINITIAL3 SSN4 MONTHBIRTH5 DAYBIRTH6 YEARBIRTH5;run;
data combinedAoDB;  merge combinedAoDB FATHERSURNAME8 AGEUNITdeath9 NUMBERAGEUNITSdth_10 SEX_11 RACE_12 MARITALSTATUS_13 STATEOFRESIDENCE_14;run;
data combinedAoDB;  merge combinedAoDB STATEOFBIRTH_15 CONTROLIDNUMBER_16 OPTIONALUSERDATA_17 BLANKFIELD_18;run;


proc contents data=combinedAoDB;run;

proc export data=work.combinedAoDB outfile='new 3 combinedAoDB.txt' 
replace; putnames=no; run;
```

Any advice on how to fix that in `sas` or `R` will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to create a fixed width file. First example here https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-do-i-write-out-a-fixed-format-file-in-sas/

Comment: And the R solution, since it was asked is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54751514/how-to-write-a-fixed-width-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot "export" to a fixed length file.  And you don't need to.  You just WRITE the fixed length file directly.

```
 data _null_;
    set work.combinedAoDB;
    file 'new 3 combinedAoDB.txt' lrecl=100 pad;
    put @1  lastname $20.
        @21 firstname $15.
        @36 middleinitial $1.
        ...
        @46 month Z2. day Z2. year Z4.
        ...
    ;
run;
```

If you have the text in that first picture as actual text (or already as a dataset) then you can use it to generate the PUT statement.  But for just 17 variables you can just type it out yourself.

Let's try some of your example data:

```
data have;
  infile cards dsd dlm='|' truncover;
  input lastname :$20. firstname :$25. middleinitial :$1. month day year;
cards4;
Abei|Ghador||07|16|1992                                            
Aziz|Patrick||07|01|1947                                            
Abele|Mat|A|04|01|1994
;;;;

filename fda temp;

data _null_;
  set have;
  file fda lrecl=100 pad;
  put @1  lastname $20.
      @21 firstname $15.
      @36 middleinitial $1.
      @46 month Z2. day Z2. year Z4.
  ;
run;

data _null_;
  infile fda ;
  input;
  list;
run;
```

Result

[image]

```
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0
1         Abei                Ghador                   07161992                                                100
2         Aziz                Patrick                  07011947                                                100
3         Abele               Mat            A         04011994                                                100
```

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your efforts. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a columnar `PUT` statement. Output values longer than the specified column range will be truncated.  Output values are according to the variable's
format.

Example:

Presume your data has column names as shown.

```
put
  LAST_NAME       1-20
  FIRST_NAME     21-35
  MIDDLE INITIAL 36
  SSN            37-45
  DOB_MONTH      46-47
  DOB_DAY        48-49
  DOB_YEAR       50-53
  FATHER_SURNAME 54-71
  AGE_UNIT       72
  AGE            73-74
  SEX            75
  RACE           76
  MARITAL_STATUS 77
  STATE_RESIDE   78-79
  STATE_BIRTH    80-81
  CONTROL_ID     82-91
  USER_DATA      92-97
  BLANK          98-100
;
```

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your efforts. Upvoted.